# If I click on Tab, it doesn't response. Why?

Tags: javascript, php

Problem is I cannot click the Tabs on the website and If i click on Tabs; it show

> Uncaught Type Error: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'value').

Is there any way to fix this? Also, I am a beginner and I don't know how to fix this. Codes are written in PHP and Javascript.

```
    <?php
// session_start();
require("checklogin.php");

$toolsname = "Matrix Setup";
$toolsnamepath = "index.php";
$userlogin = $loginname;
$usrgroup = $_SESSION["usrgrp"];

$str_tab = isset($_POST["str_tab"])? $_POST["str_tab"] : "";
$winwidth = isset($_POST["winwidth"])? $_POST["winwidth"] : "";
$ch = isset($_POST["ch"])? $_POST["ch"] : "";
$badgeno = isset($_SESSION["badgeno"])? $_SESSION["badgeno"] : "";

if($str_tab == ""){
  $str_tab = isset($_GET["str_tab"])? $_GET["str_tab"] : "";
}
if($winwidth == ""){
  $winwidth = isset($_GET["winwidth"])? $_GET["winwidth"] : "";
}
if($ch == ""){
  $ch = isset($_GET["ch"])? $_GET["ch"] : "";
}

echo "<html>";

echo "<head><title>$toolsname</title>";
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=5\">";
echo "<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">";
echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"\web/css/lotmgt_edge.css\"/>";
echo "<script src=\"lotmgt.js\"></script>\n";
echo "<script src=\"setup/setup.js\"></script>\n";
echo "<script src=\"productmatrix/productmatrix.js\"></script>\n";
echo "<script src=\"simulator/simulator.js\"></script>\n";
echo "<script src=\"addmatrix/addmatrix.js\"></script>\n";
echo "<script src=\"addAVImatrix/addmatrix.js\"></script>\n";
echo "<script src=\"\web/js/eregister/pointer.js\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>";

echo "</head>";

  echo "<body onload=OnLoad('" . $ch . "','" . $badgeno . "')>";

  //include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."\library\common\apewsheader.php");
  //include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."\library\common\db_config.inc");
  //include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."\library\common\standard_defines.inc");
  include("//sgewsnant21.amk.st.com/ewsweb/wwwroot/library/common7/apewsheader.php");
  include("//sgewsnant21.amk.st.com/ewsweb/wwwroot/library/common7/db_config.inc");
  include("//sgewsnant21.amk.st.com/ewsweb/wwwroot/library/common7/standard_defines.inc");
  include("editme.php");

    echo "<form name=\"lotmgt\" method=\"post\" target=\"_self\" onsubmit=\"return false;\">";

      echo "<div style=\"position:relative; top:20px;\">";
        echo "<table cellpadding=\"3\" cellspacing=\"0\" border=\"0\" width=\"99%\">";
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>";

                    for($c=0;$c<count($ary_tab);$c++) {
                        
                    $class_tab = (($ch=="ProductMatrix" && $ary_tab[$c]=="Product Matrix" && (!isset($str_tab) || $tr_tab=="")) || ($ch=="SocketSimulator" && $ary_tab[$c]=="Socket Simulator" && (!isset($str_tab) || $str_tab=="")) || ($ch=="AVIMatrixAdd" && $ary_tab[$c]=="AVI Matrix Add" && (!isset($str_tab) || $str_tab=="")) || ($ch=="SetupPostTest" && $ary_tab[$c]=="Setup PostTest" && (!isset($str_tab) || $str_tab=="")) || ($ch=="Setup" && $ary_tab[$c]=="Setup" && (!isset($str_tab) || $str_tab=="")) || (($c==0 && !isset($str_tab)) && $ch=="") || $ary_tab[$c] == $str_tab)? "link_tab_slct" : "link_tab";
                        echo "<a href=\"Javascript:DisplayTab('" . $ary_tab[$c] . "','str_tab');\" class=" . $class_tab . ">" . $ary_tab[$c] . "</a>";
                    }

                echo"</td>";
            echo"</tr>"; 
        echo"</table>";
      echo "</div>";
//echo $str_tab;
      if($str_tab != ""){

        switch($str_tab){
              case "Setup":
                  include("setup/setup.php");
                  break;
              case "Setup PostTest":
                  include("setup/setup.php");
                  break;
              case "Setup1":
                  include("setup1/setup.php");
                  break;
              case "Product Matrix":
                  include("productmatrix/productmatrix.php");
                  break;
              case "Socket Simulator":
                   // include("simulator/simulator.php");
                  include("simulator/Socket_simulator.php");
                  break;
             // case "Matrix Add":
               //   include("addmatrix/addmatrix.php");
              //    break;
              case "AVI Matrix Add":
                  include("addAVImatrix/addmatrix.php");
                  break;

          }
      }
      else {

        if ($ch=="ProductMatrix") {
            include("productmatrix/productmatrix.php");
          }
          else if($ch=="SocketSimulator"){
              // include("simulator/simulator.php");
              include("simulator/Socket_simulator.php");
          }
        else if($ch=="AVIMatrixAdd"){
              include("addAVImatrix/addmatrix.php");
          }
          else if($ch=="Setup"){
              include("setup/setup.php");
          }
          else if($ch=="SetupPost6E"){
              include("setup/setup.php");
          }
          else{
              include("setup/setup.php");
          }
      }

      //common
      echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"str_tab\" value=\"" . $str_tab . "\">";
      echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"winwidth\" value=\"" . $winwidth . "\">";
      echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"username\" value=\"" . $loginname . "\">";

    echo "</form>";
    flush();
    mysqli_close($conn);
    
  echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";
?>
```

Above codes are index.php codes.

```
var winplanproducttoentity = '';
var winupdateauto = '';
var winupdatebytester = '';
var winupdatebyproduct = '';
var winupdatestatus = '';
var wintestlot = '';
var winassignlot = '';
var winshowlot = ''
var winchecksicom = '';

var w;
var winwidth = window.screen.width;
var div = new Array('outputdiv','setupdiv');
//var div = new Array('outputdiv','setupdiv','availdiv');

var reqHttp  = InitRequest();
var reqHttp1 = InitRequest();
var reqHttp2 = InitRequest();
var reqHttp3 = InitRequest();


function InitRequest()  {
    var request=null;

    try { 
        request=new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    } 
    catch (e)   {   
        try { 
            request=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");    
        } 
        catch (e){ 
            request=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
        }
    }
    return request;
}

function AsynReqData(request,url,fn) {
    request.open("GET", url + '&sid=' + Date() + Math.random(), true);
  request.onreadystatechange = eval(fn);
  request.send(null);
}

function SynReqData(request,url) {      
    request.open("GET", url + '&sid=' + Date() + Math.random(), false); 
    request.send(null);
    return request.responseText;
} 

function DisplayTab(tabname,tabid) {
    document.getElementById(tabid).value = tabname;  // this is the $str_tab
    document.lotmgt.submit();
}

function OnLoad(ch,badgeno){
   
    var tab = document.lotmgt.str_tab.value; //  this is the $str_tab from DisplayTab function
    w = (winwidth < 1280)? 1280 : winwidth;
    
    if((tab=='' & ch=='') || tab=='Setup' || (ch=='Setup' & tab=='')) {  
    
    var p_1 = "checked";
    var T_0 = "checked";
    var zmiss = "checked";

        for(var i=0; i<div.length; i++) {    
            document.getElementById(div[i]).className = 'hide'; 
        }
    
        // var wd = (128*5) - 10;  
        var wd = (128*7.5) - 50;  
        var lf = 0;     
        document.getElementById('filterdiv').style.width = wd + 'px';
        document.getElementById('filterdiv').style.left = lf + 'px';

        wd = (128*5.5) - 80;
        lf = (128*5) - 10;      // lf = (128*7) - 20;   
        document.getElementById('waferdiv').style.width = wd + 'px';
        document.getElementById('waferdiv').style.left = lf + 'px';
        
//  AsynReqData(reqHttp,'setup/content_wafer.php?site=','UpdateWafer');
        AsynReqData(reqHttp1,'setup/content_filter.php?site=' + '' + '&badgeno=' + badgeno + '&p_1=' + p_1 + '&T_0=' + T_0 + '&zmiss=' + zmiss,'UpdateFilter');
    }
    
    else if (tab=='Product Matrix' || (ch=='ProductMatrix' & tab=='')){
        AsynReqData(reqHttp,'productmatrix/content_filter.php?area=','UpdatePMFilter');
    }
    // else if (tab=='Matrix Simulator' || (ch=='MatrixSimulator' & tab=='')){
    //  // AsynReqData(reqHttp,'simulator/content_filter.php?area=','UpdateSIMFilter');
    // }
    else if (tab=='Setup PostTest' || (ch=='SetupPostTest' & tab=='')){
        var p_1 = "checked";
        var T_0 = "checked";

        var wd = (128*9) - 50;  
        var lf = 0;     
        document.getElementById('filterdiv').style.width = wd + 'px';
        document.getElementById('filterdiv').style.left = lf + 'px';

        AsynReqData(reqHttp1,'setup/content_filter1.php?site=' + '' + '&badgeno=' + badgeno + '&p_1=' + p_1 + '&T_0=' + T_0,'UpdateFilter');
    }       
}

//shared functions
function ManagePopup(except){
    var mywin = new Array('winplanproducttoentity','winupdateauto','winupdatebytester','winupdatebyproduct','winupdatestatus','wintestlot','winassignlot','winshowlot','winchecksicom');

    for(var i=0; i<mywin.length; i++)   {   
        var win = window[mywin[i]];
        if (mywin[i] == except){
            if(!win.closed && win.location) win.focus();
        }
        else{
            if(!win.closed && win.location) win.close();            
        }
    }   
}

function PlanProductToEntity(product,type){
    var w = 300;
    var h = 600;
    var winl = (screen.width - w) / 2;
    var wint = (screen.height - h) / 2;     
    var winprops = 'height='+h+',width='+w+',top='+wint+',left='+winl+',toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,copyhistory=no';
    
    ManagePopup('winplanproducttoentity');
    winplanproducttoentity = this.open('../lotmgt/wip/pop_assignproduct.php?product=' + product + '&type=' + type, 'winplanproducttoentity', winprops); 
}
```

Above codes are Javascript codes. Error says in Javascript and How to fix that?

Comment: Which line of code throws the error? The message will point you to it. As a beginner, I'm guessing you didn't write all this code? FYI there are much simpler / more up-to-date tab implementations out there which don't require you to maintain your own code, don't throw errors, and don't rely on functions such as eval() which are security risks.

Comment: function DisplayTab(tabname,tabid) {
    document.getElementById(tabid).value = tabname;  // this is the $str_tab
    document.lotmgt.submit();
}

Comment: Also this code tries to set itself in a mode for Internet Explorer 5 (released in 1999, retired in 2005), so I think that gives you a clue as to its age! It's likely to be very unsuitable for modern browsers. Throw it away, it's not worth fixing.

Comment: It says that code got Uncaught Type Error: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'value').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs in the JS code and is due to the HTML generated in PHP which is missing an `id` attribute.

You seem to get the error here: `document.getElementById(tabid).value = tabname;` because `document.getElementById(tabid)` is null.

When it looks for the element with id `str_tab` it doesn't find it. The only element in the HTML which could be the desired one has the attribute `name="str_tab"` and it's your hidden field. You have to add the missing `id="str_tab"` attribute to this hidden field.

Comment: May I know where do I have to add id="str_tab" and under which line?

Comment: Just search for `name=\"str_tab\"` and add it next to it! `echo '<input type="hidden" name="str_tab" id="str_tab" value="' . $str_tab . '">';` will be easier to read than escaping always with `\"`.

Comment: I tryna find it and I didn't see that code either, so what should I do. Sorry, I'm a beginner.

Comment: If we can see it, you can find it! Just search fo `echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"str_tab\"` in your PHP file! If you can't find that then we really can't help you! Beginner or not.